# What is the difference between "./file" and "file" relative paths

Tags: php, unix, io

I always see developers including external files using these two types of relative paths. The question is, is there really a difference between"

```
require "./lib/helpers.php"
```

and

```
require "lib/helpers.php"
```

As far as I know, both points to the same file. But, does one outperform the other in terms of complexity?

Regards

Comment: `./lib` anchors the lookup in the CURRENT working directory. PHP will not search elsewhere. `lib/` allows PHP to sequentially combine this partial path with every path in the `include_path` setting, and see if the script exists there.

Comment: @MarcB so, generally if I have nothing in my include_path, they are the same

Comment: @Marc - given the number of people who don't understand the use of include_path and includes, you really ought to post this as an answer for posterity

Comment: @deadlock, you'll almost certainly have `.` in your include_path by default

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`./lib/...` anchors the include request in the script's current working directory. PHP will look for the desired file there, and no where else. If it's not there, no include is performed and execution goes on.

`lib/...` allows PHP to scan its include path, e.g. if you have

```
include_path=.:/var/lib/php:/foo/bar/baz
```

Then PHP will sequentially try

```
           ./lib/file.php
/var/lib/php/lib/file.php
/foo/bar/baz/lib/file.php
^^^^^^^^^^^^---- include path component
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^--- include() argument
```

If a match is found in the include path, then the scan stops and the file is included. If the scan runs out of candidate paths to include from, then the scan again stops but no include is performed.